# Save Order in ListView with cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview

i have ListView based on cursor adapter but during scrolling i lose the order of the data in the list, how i can save the  order of data in case i don't make it slower ,because in array adapter it was work fine unless that moving slowly during scrolling thanks on advance.

Comment: try to load all data to an object and load data into list using this object

Comment: this is not a solution may someone can help me!!!